# eshell TRAMP find remote file with relative path (or at least less than the full Tramp path)?

Tags: emacs, tramp, eshell

I love eshell's TRAMP integration. With it I can do `cd /ssh:foo:/etc` to
ssh into a remote machine and visit its `/etc/` directory. I can also do
`find-file motd` to open this file in my local emacs. However, what if I need to use sudo to change the file? I know I can give the
full path, like so:

```
find-file /sudo:foo:/etc/motd
```

but is there a way to open the file via TRAMPs sudo support, without having to type the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to came up with the following eshell alias that works for me:

```
alias sff 'find-file "${pwd}/$1"(:s/ssh/sudo/)'
```

It should be fairly obvious what it does. It prepends the working directory
path, but with the string `ssh` replaced by `sudo`. Thus it only works for
remote files accessed over ssh. I rarely edit files using sudo locally, so
that's not a problem for me. However, we can make it work for local files too, at the cost of complexity:

```
alias sff 'find-file "${pwd}/$1"(:s,^,/sudo::,:s,::/ssh:,:,)'
```

That is, prepend `/sudo::` (which is how to sudo for local files) and
subsequently replace any ocurrence of `::/ssh:` with `:`. (I would have just removed `:/ssh:`, but eshell's `:s///` construct didn't accept an empty
replacement.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative answer that works very well over at [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc31).
Using that you'd still open the file with `find-file` as usual, but then
invoke `M-x sudo-edit-current-file` (shown below) to re-open the file as root
using Tramp. I think this is a very elegant solution, because often I
initially just want to look at a file, then later find that I need to edit it.

Here's the function, in case it disappears from the page above:

```
(set-default 'tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote ((".*" "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))))
(require 'tramp)
(defun sudo-edit-current-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((position (point)))
    (find-alternate-file
     (if (file-remote-p (buffer-file-name))
         (let ((vec (tramp-dissect-file-name (buffer-file-name))))
           (tramp-make-tramp-file-name
            "sudo"
            (tramp-file-name-user vec)
            (tramp-file-name-host vec)
            (tramp-file-name-localname vec)))
       (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" (buffer-file-name))))
    (goto-char position)))
```